# Javascript: want 2 different text links to display 2 different divs (in the same place)

Tags: javascript, hidden

Not sure if i should be using a z-index or hidden approach, I've tried a few different ways and just can't get anything to work for me.

i can get a link to display one, and even have one link shuffle between the two, but i just can't seem to get 2 differnt links to work on the two different divs.

the code now is:

```
    function toggle_visibility("music" , "contact") {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
           e.style.display = 'block';

}
```

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility("music");">music</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility("contact");">contact</a>
```

`<div id="music" style="display:none;">`
`stuff`
`</div>`

`<div id="contact">`
`stuff`
`</div>`

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: added, but no good ha

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following?

http://jsfiddle.net/vhzAR/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="music_toggle">music</a>
<a href="#" id="contact_toggle">contact</a>
<div id="music" style="display:none;"> music stuff </div>
<div id="contact"> contact stuff </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle_visibility(enable, disable) {
    var e = document.getElementById(enable);
    e.style.display = 'block';
    e = document.getElementById(disable);
    e.style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('music_toggle').onclick = function() {
    toggle_visibility('music', 'contact');
};

document.getElementById('contact_toggle').onclick = function() {
    toggle_visibility('contact', 'music');
};
```

Comment: That, didn't so anything for me, unfortunatly